# Translate Date and Weather Code from Chinese to English

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

Sorry that i can't post a image straight a way cause i am new

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIUG9.png

Task-Changing a single page webpage from Chinese to English

Question:

-How to change the date to Chinese(Pointed with Black Arrow)

-How to change the weather report to English Is there any source now it's using auto ip detection to show up current weather(Pointed with Red Arrow)

Information(Here the current code translation for English will be listed within[example]):

-Pointed with Black Arrow>

`<span>
                <em id="t_date">5月16 星期四[Thursday]</em>
<!--                <em id="calen">(农历四月初七)[Chinese Calander Day]</em>
                <em id="t_time">20：30</em> -->
            </span>`

-Pointed with Red Arrow>

`<span id="weather"><iframe src="http://www.114la.com/public/widget/weather/" height="28" width="500" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no"></iframe></span>`

Answer (score 0):

If I didn't miss your point, you'd like to translate the date and weather to English version.

But I don't understand why you want to do this instead of simply using an English version weather api?

I suppose that regular expression will help but it can't do it well.

Comment: Cause there is no place for me to put the weather api which is in english version only plain text is suit to the bar